# Call to implicitly deleted default constructor when instantiating unordered_map<const char, std::string>

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I'm trying to instantiate an `std::unordered_map<const char, std::string>`:

```
std::unordered_map<const char, std::string> cities = {
    {'A', "Amsterdam"},
    {'B', "Berlin"},
    {'C', "Canberra"}
};
```

This fails with `error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'std::unordered_map<const char, std::basic_string<char>>::hasher'`. It looks like `std::hash` can't hash `const char`, but I can't find anything which would confirm it. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Keys are constant by default, you don't need to use `const` for keys.

Comment: If the keys are `const char`, you can never add a new key.

Comment: Also note that if you only care about single, upper-case letters as your keys, it might be easier to just use an array: `std::array<std::string, 'Z' - 'A'> cities { "Amsterdam", "Berlin", "Canberra"};` (and index into it with `ch - 'A'`).

Comment: @JerryCoffin thanks for the note, although in this case I'm just learning `std::unordered map`, but I'll keep it in mind

Comment: @JerryCoffin: `'A'`-`'Z'` is not guaranteed to be contiguous (as for [EBCDIC](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Binary_Coded_Decimal_Interchange_Code)).

Comment: @JerryCoffin You might want to add a note that it's not really portable. While the likelihood of the OP ever finding a system not using ASCII is getting increasingly smaller, it's still not mandated by the C++ specification.

Comment: @Jarod42: true, but irrelevant. It may end up as an array of 28 (or whatever) strings instead of 26, but that doesn't really affect much of anything.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: it'll still work just fine on an EBCDIC system. It'll have blank entries for a few extra punctuation characters, but that doesn't really cause a problem (though if you're doing to initialize entries later in the array, you probably want to use designated initializers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in documentation for [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) it is implemented through template specialization:

> Each specialization of this template is either enabled ("untainted") or disabled ("poisoned").

> The enabled specializations of the hash template defines a function object that implements a hash function. Instances of this function object satisfy Hash. In particular, they define an operator() const that...

And in section "Standard specializations for basic types" only types like `char`, `int` etc are listed, not their `const` variants. As template specialization for `non-const` and `const` versions are different those specializations do not work for `const` types. So you either need to provide your own specialization for `const char` or just use `std::uinordered_map<char,std::string>` which should be used anyway.